# Kotlin/Java formatting Double values

Tags: kotlin, formatting, double, decimal, decimalformat

My current formatting is this

```
DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format(value)
```

I need to handle values like this

```
0.00 //ok
0.45 //ok
0.002 //Need to show 0.002 or 0.0020
0.0003 //Need to show 0.0003 or 0.00030
0.00004 //Need to show 0.00004 or 0.000040
0.00234567 //Need to show 0.0023
```

But sure the above code will not work on fractional part where a non zero value started at thousandth place else I will just ended up displaying `0.00` as if it is totally a zero value. I still want the above formatting with comma when dealing with whole number but also allowing me to format when non zero starts beyond hundredths place.

Further sample

```
0.0492 // 0.04 or 0.05 much better
700.356 // 700.35 or 700.36 much better
54232.542234 // 54,232.54
```

Comment: What is the logic behind your formatting? Do you want to round the number to first two non zero decimals?

Comment: I had the same question actually. Why do your precision requirements change depending on the value? I have trouble understanding your use case, because you are ok ignoring the digit `4` in your last example `0.00234567` -> `0.0023`, but it seems important enough in your other example `0.00004`. What makes the *preceding* 0s so special here?

Comment: @Joffrey I'm not sure what is confusing or maybe it is a bad practice for you to consider. I do not want to display such `0.00023232323345345345` that long. I just want the first two non zero. Its not about the preceding zero am I right?

Comment: But also be able to work with `18888.8888` as `18,888.88` or `0.0543` as `0.054` as simple as that

Comment: @UrbanR rounding is not needed but also welcome

Comment: @UrbanR yes but only when a double fractional value is below 0.01

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS `I just want the first two non zero` - this *is* about preceding zeroes, because you're ok with 5-decimal-places precision for `0.00004` but you want only 4 for `0.00234567`. Why not `0.00234`? The only difference is in the preceding 0s, and this is surprising because this is usually not how I consider precision.

Comment: @Joffrey I just really need the ***last two*** `non-zero` digit when a value is below 0.01. Doesn't really matter how many zero will precedes. I do not know what are the possible values that I will get from API so all matter is a shorten version of any possible double value.

Comment: I understand what you want to happen, I just don't understand why you want it to happen this way. Why is it not ok to show `0.000` for the value `0.0004` (ignoring the 4th decimal place), but it's ok to show `0.023` for the value `0.0234`. You would be ignoring the same quantity in both cases. Maybe it would help to know the domain you're working on.

Comment: @Joffrey also `0.00004` can be `0.00040` its okay.

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS I think you're not getting my point. My point is that your goal doesn't have the same precision for all values (regardless of whether we show trailing 0s or not). If things are too long, why not just trim every number to a fixed number of decimal places? What is wrong with showing `0.000` for the value `0.0004`?

Comment: @Joffrey its okay but please no need to focused on `0.0234` vs `0.023` sample if I allowed that to happen will it be a solution for other set if value as well like `0.00023232323345345345`?

Comment: @Joffrey I think you are denying the problem and making it to follow your own rules instead? It's okay for me if you can't deal with the problem and required answer.

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS lol, I'm just trying to help you mate. People ask for many things on SO, and a good part of the time the problem is in the question. That's why before jumping to showing you some code to achieve what you want, I'm trying to really understand why you're trying to achieve this in the first place. You will find plenty of complicated answers here to process values and create a custom format on the fly. But the question is do you really want that? Or do you just want to round numbers like a lot of people did in the past?

Comment: @Joffrey its okay, thanks for the help as well

Comment: For instance, you said *I do not want to display such 0.00023232323345345345 that long*, but given your requirements, you're ok displaying `0.000000000000000000004` that long, right? This is the reason why I'm asking *What is wrong with showing 0.000 for the value 0.0004?*. You still haven't answered that question. But if you're initial goal is to reduce the size of the output, you'll have to take this case into account in your requirements.

Comment: @Joffrey yes that is right since I will most likely not get that kind of long preceded 0 since the API is working with currency

Comment: @Joffrey Yes you can straight to the point ask that as well, for my part it is a lack of further sample case. But again I will repeat it I just need the last two non zero or the part where non zero start that should already mean that it is okay for me the possibility of `0.000000000000000000004` though will not happened.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `What is wrong with showing 0.000 for the value 0.0004`. I already stated many times already if you will just accept the case requirements and not making it to follow your version instead. All I need is the last two non zero (0.00234567 which is 0.0023) or first non zero (0.0004 which is 0.0004 or 0.00040) in the decimal. This is comment section is getting too long its okay if you can't deal with it, really no problem at all. If you really want to answer you are welcome as well.

Comment: yours : `you're ok with 5-decimal-places precision for 0.00004 but you want only 4 for 0.00234567. Why not 0.00234?`  mine:  ``0.0234 vs 0.023 sample if I allowed that to happen will it be a solution for other set if value as well like 0.000023232323345345345`` You still haven't answered that question. For me it really does not make any change whether we allowed it to be 3 decimal places, lets not focus on a wrong problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try multiplying the number by 10 until you know you got to two non zero digits. This way you will get the number of decimal points you have to round up.

After that you use the NumberFormat to format the number like this:

```
val format = NumberFormat.getInstance()
format.maximumFractionDigits = nrOfDecimalPoints
val formattedNumber = format.format(yourNumber)
```

This way you will keep the thousands separator "," and the decimal will be cut off after two non zero digits.

**EDIT**

This is how the custom function looks like:

```
private fun customFormat(number: Double): String{
    var temp = number - number.toInt()
    temp *= 100
    var nrDec = 2
    if (number <= 0.0){
        return "0.00"
    }
    if (temp >= 1.0){
        val format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US)
        format.maximumFractionDigits = nrDec
        return format.format(number)
    }
    while (temp < 1.0 && nrDec < 15){
        temp *= 10
        nrDec ++
    }
    if((temp * 10 % 10) != 0.0){
        nrDec++
    }
    val format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US)
    format.maximumFractionDigits = nrDec
    return format.format(number)
}
```

Comment: How can we say that we already break it down to last two non zero?

Comment: Just compare it after you mulitply it by 10. If it is not equal to 0 you get the first non zero digit, then you multiply it again by 10 and check the new number if it's divisble by 10 and if it is not, you know that the next digit is also not zero.

Comment: care to give your whole solution so we can test it in actual?

Comment: By the way I updated the question a little bit since @Joffrey is getting confuse as it should be depends on preceded zero

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS Edited my answer with the whole function.

Comment: Thanks checking it now!

Comment: Not enough see a new set of sample value above

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS i dont understand now... In case of number 0.0492, why are you ok with showing just 0.04 instead of 0.049? Didn't you say you want to show first two non zero decimals???

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS I edited my solution so it works on your additional cases

Comment: Almost but I get `0.01` instead of `0.012` or `0.013` from `0.012846708941213928`

Comment: `1.0817282022816934` becomes `1` instead of `1.081` or `1.082`

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS Why do you want 0.012846708941213928 to become 0.013, but in your post you gave an example 0.0492 to become 0.05? This doesn't make any sense. Sometimes you want to round just to two decimal points, but sometimes you want to round to first two non zero... Also i checked for 1.0817282022816934, it works fine and rounds to 1.08 (using the logic from your post, not your comment)

Comment: You are right lets forget the rounding I just added that rounding is also acceptable but will literally make it too complicated, will test it more while waiting for other answer. Does this work on negative values such as `-0.0052342`?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS this won't work for negative numbers, maybe set a flag that it is negative, use the absolute value and later convert back to negative

Comment: What is 15 here?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this in order to cut of tailing 0:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    double number1 = 0.2;
    double number2 = 1.55;
    double number3 = 0.00005;
    double number4 = 0.50000;
    
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00#########");
    System.out.println(df.format(number1)); // 0.20
    System.out.println(df.format(number2)); // 1.55
    System.out.println(df.format(number3)); // 0.00005
    System.out.println(df.format(number4)); // 0.50
 }
```

You just need to know how far your decimal digits should be checked.

Comment: I don't think this will solve the OP's last case though.

Comment: You're right. In that case, I would do a simple workaround formatting the number as explained and cut it off after 2 non-0 digits are shown using REGEX..